# C# XmlSerializer generates wrong XML string

Tags: c#, xml

I use the following code to serialize my class as XML string:

```
AXMLItem rc = new AXMLItem();

rc.Attributes.Add(new Reports.ReportConfiguration.Questionnaire.FormObjectXMLItem.Attribute { Value = "ddddd" });

MemoryStream fw = new MemoryStream();

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AXMLItem ));

        using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, rc);
            }
            string myString = textWriter.ToString(); //This is the output as a string
        }
```

that class definition

```
 [XmlType(TypeName = "A")]
 public class AXMLItem
 {
        [XmlType(TypeName = "B")]
        public List<Attr> Attrs { get; set; }

        [XmlType(TypeName = "C")]
        public class Attr
        {
            [XmlText]
            public string Value { get; set; }
        }

        public AXMLItem()
        {
             Attrs = new List<Attr>();
        }
 }
```

which gives me the following string

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
    <A xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <B>
           <C>ddddd</C>
        </B>
    </A>
```

but I need

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
    <A xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <C>ddddd</C>
    </A>
```

Keep in ming that there can be many `<C>...</C>` items. How to fix it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just add an `XmlElement` attribute to the collection property:

```
    [XmlElement("C")]
    public List<Attr> Attrs { get; set; }
```